# Can KNIME be used in the DevSpace like react projects?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, knime, azure-dev-spaces

Using "https://devspace.sh/" in Ubuntu, Is it possible to have KNIME, Kafka and python be used for containerizing in dev space? Currently their documentation is about the react, vue and other web based apps only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [DevSpace](https://devspace.sh) works with any language, any framework and any IDE. So, you can definitely work on a python application using the hot reloading feature and then also deploy a Kafka cluster using DevSpace which you are using from the python application.

Check out the Helm deployments section for details on how to deploy Kafka using DevSpace's Helm integration: https://devspace.sh/cli/docs/configuration/deployments/helm-charts